# Are CoD Black Ops 3 emblem and clan tag locked because of a bug or a required task?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I've been doing some search under why multiplayer emblems and clan tag are locked (Since release till now, November), but couldn't find a clear answer. Does anyone know whether it is because of a bug or a required task such as leveling up or playing campaign mode?

Either way it's not clear, and some of my friends can already change their emblems and set up a clan tag, but it's too soon to tell whether it's because of a level, because they're around 35+, and I'm still at lvl 27,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Emblem and calling card (callsign) unlocks happen by doing certain tasks within the game. If you are looking for specific multiplayer emblems, any of the additional special emblems are unlocked through black market purchases from cryptokeys (obtained by playing multiplayer matches).

If you are looking to create emblems, I recommend checking this site out as it houses quite a few tutorials on making emblems. http://www.codplayercards.com/

As for the clan tag, it will typically unlock at a certain level, which you are a higher level than I am, and I have it unlocked, so I would assume it should be unlocked for you. One idea is to make sure that you have "User generated content" turned on. 
On the main multiplayer screen, click on the menu icon in the bottom right. Then go to the options tab and go to the content filter option. Set "User generated content" to enabled and this should allow you to update your clan tag (and may resolve issues with emblems for you too). See this youtube video if my directions did not make sense.

Comment: Enabling "User Generated Content" did the trick